# javascript Firebase how to fire 'value' events in sequence?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a function firing two 'value' Firebase events. One is necessary to get the number of children, which is corresponding to the deepest path of the next one.

```
function myFunction(data){
//get last child 
var lastchild = 0;
var data_child = firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + 633 + '/' + 630);
data_child.once('value', function(child) {
    if(child.exists()){
        lastchild = child.numChildren();
        console.log('function 1');
    }else{
        console.log('error no child');
    }
});
//use this number to read the path
var msgsStored = firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + 633 + '/' + 630 + '/' + lastchild);
    msgsStored.orderByChild('datetime').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var store = (snapshot.val());
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log('function 2');
        //do something
        }
    }
}//myFunction
```

Firebase will always fire the last 'value' event before the first one. Why?
That will result always on variable lastchild = 0; and 'function 2' will always print before 'function 1' on console.
I tried also creating a callback(); function to try control the order with JavaScript, but will not work. 
I know different events of Firebase are fired in different order, but in my case I need to read stored data only. 
Anybody knows what am I missing and how to address me to a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase, like most of the modern web, reads data from its database asynchronously. This is easiest to see by placing some log statements in your code:

```
console.log("1");
var data_child = firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + 633 + '/' + 630);
data_child.once('value', function(child) {
  console.log("2");
});
console.log("3");
```

The output of this is:

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 2

This is probably not what you initially expected, but explains a lot on the behavior you're seeing. When log statement 3 executes, the data from the first listener hasn't been loaded yet. So you can't make a query based on that data.

For this reason you always need to move the code that requires the data **into** the callback:

```
var lastchild = 0;
var data_child = firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + 633 + '/' + 630);
data_child.once('value', function(child) {
    if(child.exists()){
        lastchild = child.numChildren();

        //use this number to read the path
        var msgsStored = firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + 633 + '/' + 630 + '/' + lastchild);
    
        msgsStored.orderByChild('datetime').once('value', function(snapshot) {
            var store = (snapshot.val());
            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                console.log('function 2');
                //do something
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.log('error no child');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer makes totally sense, and I just couldn't think about it. Thank you for the explanation and for open my mind.

Comment: You're welcome Adry. This is one of the major stumbling blocks when you get started with web APIs, so I'm happy to help you get over it.